# Log showing "!" exclamation mark after running a SAS macro

Tags: macros, sas, sas-macro

I created a macro. However, when I run it,a exclamation mark (without errors or warnings) is shown in front of the line in my log.

I tested it out without the *macroname*, it would work. Is it because of the underscore? How come? Thank you!  -Michelle

```
    %macro _macroname_transpose(data_new,visit_num,
   ! neurophys_score);
     proc transpose data=epic.exercise1 out=&data_new
     prefix=&visit_num;
    by cid;
    id vnum;
    var &neurophys_score;
    run;
   %mend _macroname_transpose;
```

Answer (score 3):

The exclamation point in a simple indicator that the log line is a continuation of the one above it.  This will happen a lot if your session linesize setting is small.  If the linesize is made larger, more information will fit in a single log line, but you may have to scroll right to see it all.

```
options linesize = MAX; * 250 if I recall ;
options linesize = 120;

… your code here …
```

A source code line length can be any length you want, and is not affected by the linesize (LS) option.  LS affects output to the log and the ODS listing destination.  When the source line is longer than LS the log will contain the continuation character.

Comment: Thank you Richard. I set my ls = 70 at the beginning of my script. linesize =120 fixed it!

Comment: Great, and welcome to Stackoverflow.  Be sure to read the [help] and mark the response that best helped you as the answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer